# Did I pay a fee to transfer from Coinbase to Blockchain?

Tags: transaction-fees

I recently transferred from Coinbase to my Blockchain wallet. At the time and in my transaction summary it shows a fee of .0002 . However I still have the same amount I started with. Who paid this fee? It didn't seem to come out of my btc.

Answer (score 9):

Coinbase covered the fee. I believe they do this in order to simplify things for their users (so that if it says you have x BTC, you can transfer x BTC, not (x minus transaction fees) BTC).

Of course, they pass the cost along to their users in their buy/sell price and fees.